# Как создать Generic для хука useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-типы

Существует тип SuccessResponseResult, который имеет тип TData:

```
export type SuccessResponseResult<TData> = {
    code?: number;
    success: true;
    message?: string;
    data: TData;
};
```

Как можно прикрепить TData к responseData, где TData - projectBody?

```
const [responseData, setResponseData] = useState<SuccessResponseResult<T> | null>(null)

const handleSubmit = useCallback( (values) => {
    const projectBody = {
        title: values.title,
        client: values.client,
        status: values.status
    }
}, [values])
```

Comment: `useState<SuccessResponseResult<T>` - что такое `T` здесь?

Comment: Начал писать свой Generic, обозначил его как T

Comment: что такое `projectBody`? Это тип или переменная? Достаточно вместо `T` указать нужный тип